# Send shipping email using an Observer

Tags: event-observer, email, shipment

I've managed to create an Observer to automatically create a shipment when an invoice is created.

The problem I have is with the final part of the code to send the email once the shipment has been created.

I wanted to ask if anyone can notice what is wrong with the `$sendEmail` call in my code.

Here's my Observer code for `_saveShipment()`

```
        protected function _saveShipment(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment $shipment, Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order, $customerEmailComments = '')
        {
            $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
            Mage::log($shipment->debug(),Zend_Log::INFO,'shipment.log',true);
            $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                ->addObject($shipment)
                ->addObject($order)
                ->save();

            $emailSentStatus = $shipment->getData('email_sent');
            if($emailSentStatus)
                Mage::log("Email has been sent",Zend_Log::INFO,'email.log',true);
            else
                Mage::log("IS FALSE",Zend_Log::INFO,'email.log',true);
//                Mage::log($customerEmailComments,Zend_Log::INFO,'email.log',true);
            if (!is_null($customerEmail) && !$emailSentStatus) {
                $shipment->setEmailSent(true);
                $shipment->sendEmail(true, $customerEmailComments);
            }

            return $this;
        }
```

Thanks for you time...

Comment: Have you checked whether the `if`clause is actually true?

Comment: @user3154108 Hi, yes my if condition is coming back as "FALSE" I'm trying to find out why is isn't send `2014-08-04T13:52:33+00:00 INFO (6): IS FALSE`

Comment: Where is `$customerEmail` define in `if (!is_null($customerEmail)..`?

Comment: Yeah, R.S is right, $customerEmail does not seem to be defined, giving an eternel null and thus a false in the if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$customerEmail` is not define try

```
.....
if (!is_null($shipment->getOrder()->getCustomerEmail()) && !$emailSentStatus) {
    $shipment->sendEmail(true, $customerEmailComments);
    $shipment->setEmailSent(true);
 }
```

Comment: Thankyou, that solved it `$customerEmail` was not defined

Answer (score 1):

Just change the position

```
$shipment->sendEmail(true, $customerEmailComments);
 $shipment->setEmailSent(true);
```

to

```
$shipment->setEmailSent(true);
$shipment->sendEmail(true, $customerEmailComments);
```

Also sales Shipment email `sendEmail()` depends on  `condition:Mage::helper('sales')->canSendNewShipmentEmail($storeId)`

Check Shipment setting is enable from admin

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for you response, I have made the changes and checked in admin but I am still not getting an email sent and the log still says `2014-08-04T14:21:07+00:00 INFO (6): IS FALSE` :(